# Persistent volume claims vs subPath

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

I would like to use a single mount point on a node (ie `/data`) and have a different sub folder for each `PersistentVolumeClaim` that I am going to use in my cluster.

At the moment I have multiple `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolume` for each sub folder, for example:

```yaml
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: prometheus
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: "/data/prometheus"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: disk
              operator: In
              values:
                - local
```

As you can image having a `StorageClass`, a `PersistentVolume` for each `PersistentVolumeClaim` looks a bit of an overkill.

I have tried to use a single `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolume` (just pointing to  `/data`), the `usePath` option (ie `prometheus`) with multiple `PersistentVolumeClaim`.
But I have noticed that if the `securityContext.fsGroupChangePolicy` option is enabled it will apply the user/group changes to root of the volume (ie `/data`) not to the `subPath` (ie `/data/prometheus`).

Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions; administration questions about specific filesystem setups on Kubernetes nodes might be better asked on a different Stack Exchange site like [sf] or [devops.se].  As an application developer I wouldn't expect you to need either of the objects you show here, the cluster will create the PersistentVolume automatically from the PersistentVolumeClaim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[local-path-provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner) seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can image having a StorageClass, a PersistentVolume for each
> PersistentVolumeClaim looks a bit of an overkill.

That's exactly how [dynamic storage provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/) works. Single storage class specified in PVC used by a pod will provision single PV for that PVC. There's nothing wrong with it. I'd suggest using it if you are ok with its default volume reclaim policy of delete.

Comment: But my kubernetes cluster is self-hosted, it is not on the cloud. Could you have a dynamic storage provisioning not on the cloud? Thanks

Comment: of course you can, see my blog post about [Dynamic Provisioning of Kubernetes Storage](https://www.rokpoto.com/kubernetes-storage-dynamic-provisioning/). I used `minikube` and its default storage class for dynamic storage provisioning. But you can use any (non-cloud) storage class in your self-hosted Kubernetes cluster. What matters is what provisioner you use.

Comment: Can you point me to an example? Thanks

Comment: edited my previous comment

Comment: see also [nfs provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner) and storage class example using it